# How to call a function just before the *ngFor loop? ::Angular2

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, angular, typescript

First of all, I have a http request, which looks like:

```
private getValues() {
  this._watchlistElements.map(v =>
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/getValue/' + v.xid)
    .subscribe(res => {
      this._values.push(res.json());
    }));
};
```

Everything works good, but the problem is that it returns a chaotic, unsorted array of objects. I want to sort it, that's why I've made a separate sorting function:

```
private sortPoints(){
  this._values.sort((a,b) => a.ts - b.ts);
}
```

The elements from `_values` variable are being shown by `*ngFor` loop:

```
<tr *ngFor="let elem of _values">
```

The `getValues()` function is being called every 5 secs in an interval:

```
this.loadPoints = setInterval(() => {
  this.getValues();
}, 5000);
```

Now I have to call the sorting function - `sortPoints()` - somewhere. I thought this way will be fine:

```
this.loadPoints = setInterval(() => {
  this.getValues();
  this.sortPoints();
}, 5000);
```

But unfortunately it doesn't affect the array. The `*ngFor` loop just fills the table with unsorted elements. But if I just make a simple button:

`<button (click)="sortPoints()">Sort it!</button>`

The array is being sorted dynamically, just right after the button click.

**Then my question is** if you would have any other ideas where to place the function to make this mechanism work?

Any help highly appreciated.

> **EDIT** Implemented the @Sasxa solution, received following errors:

[image]

Comment: Because  this.getValues(); is asynch call   this.sortPoints(); after you assign values i.e after this._values.push(res.json());

Comment: If you're doing this just for display purposes then look at OrderBy

Comment: @George OrderBy is a pipe. Ive tried to solve it with pipes but it didn't work properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can chain observable operators and process the stream, so at the end (when you subscribe) you have the values just as you like:

```ts
private getValues() {
  this._watchlistElements.map(v =>
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/getValue/' + v.xid)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .map(data => this._values.push(data))
      .map(() => this._values.sort((a,b) => a.ts - b.ts))
      .subscribe(sorted => this._values = sorted));
};
```

Comment: Somehow it doesn't work. Error appears: `values.sort` is not a function. Also Webstorm colores the `map` in the `.map(res => res.json())` line and warns that its an unresolved function or method.

Comment: Data you're getting from http isn't array. If you want to store data in array and sort it after, it's best to create a pipe.

Comment: Isn't an array? If I `console.log` the `_values` variable, it says that it's an array of objects... It has also a prototype of Array...

Comment: `_values` is array, but `response.json()` isn't, and in my example, sort() runs on response data, not _values... I updated the answer, that might work. If not, move some things around, something similar will work...

Comment: You have amazed me with that answer. I didn't even had a single thought that the response may not be an array. Is there any other way to solve it, without using pipes? I've already tried to do it by pipe and it didnt work.